# Confusion about probabilities.

Tags: probability, soft-question, problem-solving, intuition

Ok so far what I understand is this let's say... Having to draw a card from $52$ card-deck its probability is of course $\dfrac1{52}$. Now the probability to say that I will keep drawing this same card $10$ times of course it is $\dfrac1{(52)^{10}}$ because now I have a lot more possibilities. Now my question is this. I also know that drawing a card at a specific time has the same probability of $\dfrac1{52}$ no matter what you drew before. Is it wrong to assume that the fact that you drew $9$ times the same card it is most likely that it won't happen again. Because as a whole fact the probability is $\dfrac1{52^{10}}$. Let's consider that you don't know what you drew before. It is somehow very counter intuive. I know the math I think but I can't dygest it. I mean when we play games that have the "random" element in them I mostly do well because I go with my intuition like they say "lightning doesnt hit the same spot twice".

Comment: I think it is wrong to think that because the cards have no memory. provided you return the card back into the deck and randomly shuffle it the probability remains the same no matter how many times it happened before.

Comment: Souns like a [Monty Hall problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem). BTW you use important assumption, but didn't express it, that the card drawn is returned to the deck (and possibly the deck is shuffled again) before the next draw.

Comment: Of course i agree wit you and i understand the math .But the math also say that drawing the same card many times it is not likekly.BUt they also say that drawing a card at a certain time has a standar probability which i also agree but it is very counter ituitive.That is all.

Comment: Also, lightning does strike the same place twice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieKhQd5LzAs or more like 50 times!

Comment: The Monty hall problem at its simplest way it is easy using only you intuition.For example it is not likekly to hae picked the correct door from the start because you had to pick from 3 doors.

Comment: If you have examined the deck of cards and made sure it is a normal deck of cards, *and* if you use a (provably correct) shuffling method, then there will be no change in the probability of drawing a particular card again, no matter how many times you drew it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question it seems you are asking about can be phrased as follows:

> Given that I have selected the ace of spades 9 times in a row (with replacement), what is the probability that, upon drawing another card at random, I will draw the ace of spades again?

The traditional mathematical answer is that, assuming that all cards have the same basic properties, the chances of drawing any two cards are the same.  It would follow that the probability of drawing the ace of spades is necessarily 1/52, regardless of what had occurred previously.  The deck does not "remember" what has happened before, so the probability of drawing a particular card, which is a property of the deck, should not change.

It is a common mistaken belief that if one outcome occurs with unusual frequency, the odds must be shifted in favor of other outcomes in order for the frequencies to "balance out".  This mistaken belief is referred to as the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

That being said: one might say that certain outcomes are "suspicious" and perhaps reveal that the system isn't "fair" as you may have assumed.  For example, if you rolled a six-sided die and got a 1 ten times in a row, you might think that perhaps the die is loaded.

It is often useful to adjust your guess of what the underlying probabilities are with a [Bayesian update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference).

Comment: Ye of course i know that .It is just counter intuitive.I know the deck does not have any memory .But it is also correct to say that drawing 100 times ace of spades is very unlikekly .

Comment: Yes, but it is equally unlikely that you'll draw any exact sequence of 100 cards.  I think this is the key to the gambler's fallacy; we're biased towards certain patterns.

Comment: Ohhh yeah you are right .Tha is where all the problem was i think.Thank you i think it is not counter intuitive any more .Guess smarter people had better intuition and had figured out all these things when they where creating those probability systems :D

Answer (score 1):

You're right, given that you have drawn $9$ times the same card, it is unlikely to draw the same card again, just as it is if you had drawn that card only once or one hundred times, namely $\frac{1}{52}$. I think where your intuition goes wrong is that you fix your attention on one specific card if it appears a lot. Given that one specific card (or lightning spot) the chance is pretty low to get it if you compare it with its complement: not that card. However, if you compare it with the probability to getting any other card, they are of course all the same.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if I draw the same card from a deck 9 times, I would think that there is some kind of trick, and that next time I would draw the same card again.

But if I'm sure that the deck is like expected, that is, with 52 different cards that have all the same probability of being drawn, then there is no doubt: no matter what have you drawn before, the probability is always the same. The skepticism that some people shows before this fact is perhaps because of the very little probability of that a random experiment yields many times the same result.